# Creating a material table with dynamic class object

Tags: html, angular, dynamic, angular8

I need to create a table in html (with less back end ts code) from the data that is coming from an API.
The data will be coming in the below way (mocked up for this question)

```
{ strTableName: "TestTable",  strComment:"Approved", 
        lstTableHeaders:[
          {strFieldName : "Sl No.", strType:"Numeric", lstComments:[]},
          {strFieldName : "Description", strType:"string", lstComments:[]},
          {strFieldName : "Units", strType:"Numeric", lstComments:[]},
          {strFieldName : "Total", strType:"Amount", lstComments:[]},
        ], TableData:
        {
          lstRowData:[
            {iID: 1, lstCellData:[
              {strFieldName:"Sl No.", strValue:"1", strComment:"", strBackgroundColor:"green"},
              {strFieldName:"Description", strValue:"Item 1", strComment:"", strBackgroundColor:"red"},
              {strFieldName:"Units", strValue:"1", strComment:"", strBackgroundColor:"green"},
              {strFieldName:"Total", strValue:"500", strComment:"", strBackgroundColor:"yellow"},
            ]},
            {iID: 2, lstCellData:[
              {strFieldName:"Sl No.", strValue:"2", strComment:"", strBackgroundColor:"green"},
              {strFieldName:"Description", strValue:"Item 2", strComment:"", strBackgroundColor:"red"},
              {strFieldName:"Units", strValue:"3", strComment:"", strBackgroundColor:"green"},
              {strFieldName:"Total", strValue:"1500", strComment:"", strBackgroundColor:"yellow"},
            ]},
          ]
        }
      }
```

The background color will be used as the cell bg color and comment will be used to pop up the data when the mouse is hovered on the cell. That comes under the styling but i need the table to be created from this data. 
is this possible?
(Tried searching a lot of questions from github, stackoverflow and even going through documents from angular. asking this question as a final resort.)

Edit : have the below code in html to make the headers appear. still struggling to get the data in the table.

```
              <mat-table #table>
                <ng-container *ngFor="let column of item.lstTableHeaders" [matColumnDef]="column.strFieldName">
                  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ column.strFieldName }}</mat-header-cell>
                  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let column">{{ column.strFieldName }}</mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
                <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="item.displayedTableHeaders()"></mat-header-row>
                <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedTableHeaders();"></mat-row>
              </mat-table>
```

and in ts file : i added one more function for the table model:

```
public displayedTableHeaders() : string[]{
        return this.lstTableHeaders.map(x=> x.strFieldName);
    }
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To any one who is wondering, I solved this by creating a function which gives the current row number and field name as a keyvalue pair and used that as a data source. 
Then the cell data will be another function that gets the current row number and field name and gets the value from that combination. 
Only drawback with this was i have to write a event that detects the changes and use that value to set the original model, but was willing to do that to achieve a fully dynamic table.

```
public TableSource() {
        var item : any;

        var jsonToBeUsed = [];
        var finalJson = [];

        this.objTableData.lstRowData.forEach(x => {
            x.lstCellData.forEach(y => {
                item = {};
                item.key = x.iID;
                item.value = y.strFieldName;
                jsonToBeUsed.push(item);
            },
            )
            finalJson.push(jsonToBeUsed),
            jsonToBeUsed = [];

        }
        )
        return finalJson;

    }
```

use this function as a data source

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="item.TableSource()">
...
 <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
<div contenteditable="true" (keyup)="tableValueChanged(item.strTableName, column.strFieldName, row, $event.target.textContent)">{{gettablevalue(item.strTableName,row[0],column.strFieldName)}}</div>
 </mat-cell>
...
</mat-table>
```

Got it working now !!